# Is it ok if index length and data length are shorter after a backup

Tags: mysql, wordpress, backup

I created a backup of my mysql db 5.x using wp-db-backup plugin. I noticed that the rows, auto-increment counter all look like the original. Except, the data length and index length which shows smaller values. Do you know if this is a sign that the backup is not good?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because, when you restore a database the data are written from scratch in your tables and you have no unused space in the data-store, it's like running an OPTIMIZE table on the tables of your database. Your data and indexes are re-created.

Unused space is normal when you do a lot of insert/delete , and tipically is present in the `wp-options` table which is used by plugins to save the options.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want just to confirm that when you said yes, you meant, it is normal that the numbers differ for these parameters and that the backup is OK. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes, it's ok! As in my reply you are "rebuilding" your tables from scratch!